# Do Filipinos need a visa to vacation in the US?

Tags: visas, usa, filipino-citizens

Do I need visa if I want to go to Dallas, Texas to watch the Dallas Mavericks play in NBA? And if I do, what are the requirements or procedures when applying in the Philippines?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. One of the expectations of StackExchange is that you demonstrate some initial research effort; for example, have you review the [visas page](https://ph.usembassy.gov/visas/) from the U.S. Embassy to the Philippines, and the [visitor visa application website](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/ph/ph-niv-typeb1b2.asp)? If you have specific questions that are not answered authoritatively by official sources, please [edit] your post to include them. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Filipino nationals **do** require a visa to enter the US, regardless of the duration of stay.

You will need to fill out [this application form](https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/), and book an appointment with the US embassy in Manila for an interview. Bring your application form (along with anything specified in it), your passport and **any and all** proof of your ties to the Philippines.

They will then assess youir application, and hopefully you'll be given the visa.